# Distributed Computing: Equivalent of a PaaS?

Tags: cloud, distributed-computing, paas

I'm looking to do internet-based Distributed Computing for an application I'm creating.

Are there any frameworks, services, or the like, which anyone is aware of which will allow me to do this in a fashion using the cloud? I'd love to be able to spin up 1 to x, instances to perform certain portions of a large task as needed (And spin down the instances when not used).

I'd love it if the offering was as close to a PaaS concept as possible, where I only have to worry about my code.

All the cloud offerings I've seen seem to be focused towards scaling to handle many copies of doing one task (Serving your website), verses having a capability to scale up to distribute a task.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine has several capabilities that you can use.

One possibility is Modules (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/) which allows you to break up an app into multiple components operating in parallel. You can create any distributed computation mechanism you want.  Each module can scale automatically to multiple instances depending on how heavily you use it.

Another possibility is Task Queues (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) which provide particular mechanisms for distribed computation.

*(Disclosure: I'm on the Google Cloud development team.)*